# How to to make Django default id (pk) to random and bigger in length

Tags: django, django-models

I am creating an where in my model Profile i am getting the default id with the name id, but the issue it is generating ids from 0 to onwards like 1,2,. What I want is a random id which should also be longer length like 343347 etc.

Comment: Would a UUIDField work? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield

Comment: Is it possible to override build in id?

Comment: yes, just set `primary_key=True` to the field you want to use. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields

Answer (score 2):

Use a `UUIDField`. Copied from [the doc:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield)

> A field for storing universally unique identifiers. Uses Python’s UUID
> class. When used on PostgreSQL, this stores in a uuid datatype,
> otherwise in a char(32).
>
> Universally unique identifiers are a good alternative to AutoField for
> primary_key. The database will not generate the UUID for you, so it is
> recommended to use default:
>
> ```
> import uuid from django.db import models
>
> class MyUUIDModel(models.Model):
>     id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
>     # other fields
> ```
>
> Note that a callable (with the parentheses omitted) is passed to
> default, not an instance of UUID.

Comment: SO this UUID is giving me a string can I get only number in the output?

Comment: Find a replacement for `uuid.uuid4` which returns the uuid as a string of digits or as an integer. The string is more user-friendly in terms of spotting typing errors when it has to be entered manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code. But it is possible to have a duplicate number and make an error.

```
import random

def big_random():
    return random.randint(1000000, 9999999)


class Foo(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(default=big_random, primary_key=True)
    bar = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

I suggest use uuid as pk:

```
import uuid

class Foo(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True)
    bar = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Comment: Will fail with a duplicate primary key with low probability, which increases as the table fills up. 1 in 9 million to start with but 1 in 9000 once 1000 entries in the table.

Comment: of course, UUID is a better choice. But he/she wants this :)).

Comment: No, he wants something that works for all values of works, and that is test-able. I could suggest how to "fix" it, but not test it, but its basically a case of the WRONG THING. Just DON'T!

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is for a unique 32-bit bit integer entity that can be used in place of a pk in URLs, you could use a reversible 1 to 1 mapping function within that domain. This would not be secure but would prevent people who do not have access to your source code from "fishing" for the next or previous pk.

Using CBVs, you would at one end decode the "pk" that isn't a pk, for example in a subclassed `get_object` method, and at the other end generate URLs using for example

```
reverse( 'app:name', kwargs={ 'pk': my_mapping_function( object.pk) } )
```

I won't volunteer such a mapping function because by publishing it, I instantly render it far less useful!  (A trivial one would be to permute the bits of the integer pk into a new order. Consult a mathematician for less trivial ones).

I still stand by my comment that this is an example of a **wrong thing**. If guessing pk values compromises application security, then "security by obscurity" is no better, and this answer is an example of such.

This said, [Hashids](https://hashids.org/) might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The popular package [django-extensions](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) has a few options for such fields.

Particularly they have options for **ShortUUIDField** and **RandomCharField** (and **AutoSlugField** if you want to automate the generation of slug fields).
Please see [this post](https://dev.to/spikelanterncom/options-for-public-facing-ids-in-django-1i3c)